# How to make a drop-down list in excel and displaying the data acording to the selection?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a drop down list to select the month(luna) and so my data changes in the table.

I've tried making a drop down list according to the help found on Google but i thing i'm not doing it in the right way.

[image: Example table]

Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is you need to create a separate list of months somewhere else, where each month appears only once, and use that to form your drop-down. You then need to use an array formula for indexing all of the real information that then populates your table based on the value of the cell that holds your drop-down. At the moment though you haven't demonstrated any concrete steps towards this; if you include parts of how far you got, I will construct an answer if you get stuck.

Comment: Hello,
I haven't worked so far with array formulas. I've tried to understand using this article [https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7], but i don't get it.